# ReferenceError: member is not defined in Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const { MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  
      name: 'guildMemberAdd',
      execute(message, Discord, client, guild) {
      const channelId = '918746332435468288' // welcome channel
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Welcome ${member.user.username}`)
        .setColor(`EEA83B`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome \`${member.username}\` To The Floppacord! Have Fun And Be Sure To Follow The Rules In <#860428690034917406>`)
        .setThumbnail(guild.avatarURL)
        .setFooter({ text: member.name + "#" + member.discriminator, iconURL: member.avatarURL})
  channel.send(member.tag)
  channel.send(embed)
      }}
```

Hey, sorry for the bad coding, im new to this sort of thing. But when I try using this in my bot, i get this error: **[Bot] ReferenceError: member is not defined**. Any help would be appreciated :)

P.s Im using discord.js v12.5.3 if thats important

Comment: what is `const member = guildMemberAdd` supposed to be? Where does the value `guildMemberAdd` come from?

Comment: @Elitezen that was something i stupidly tried, i should've taken that out. Sry :)

Comment: So, where is `member` defined?

Comment: @derpirscher  im not sure how to define it. Normally i would use something like ```const member = message.mentions.members.first()``` but since this is an event i know i cant use that. so im honestly not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an event listener for the `guildMemberAdd` event, you would get a parameter which is the member who joined the server by default. So if you had an event listener like this, you could just use the `member` without defining it anywhere:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    // ...
})
```

Looking at your code, it seems like you have a command handler and have tried to put an event in it, which I don't think it would work. Another way you could do this is if you created the event listener in your main file (eg: `index.js`) and then execute a piece of code when the event runs. An example:

index.js:

```js
import guildMemberFunctionFile from 'your/file/path/tothecommand'
\\ ...

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    guildMemberFunctionFile.execute(member)
})

\\ ...
```

Your event code:

```js
function execute(member) {
    // Execute something
}
exports.execute = execute
```

Comment: Thanks, i added it to my index.js file like you said and it works now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'guildMemberAdd',
  execute(message, Discord, client, guild, member) {
    const channelId = '918746332435468288' // welcome channel

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Welcome ${member.user.username}`)
      .setColor(`EEA83B`)
      .setDescription(`Welcome \`${member.username}\` To The Floppacord! Have Fun And Be Sure To Follow The Rules In <#860428690034917406>`)
      .setThumbnail(guild.avatarURL)
      .setFooter({ text: member.name + "#" + member.discriminator, iconURL: member.avatarURL });

    channel.send(member.tag);
    channel.send(embed);
  }
}
```

i hope your code is an event and not a command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).